# Logging successful / unsuccessful Spring context initialization

Tags: spring, logging, loading

I need to log whether the Spring context was initialized correctly in a log file. If all the beans were wired and loaded correctly, I need to log that, as well as an incorrect initialization...

I have created the appender and the log file, but the problem is that I don't know if there is something in Spring to log those two events and how can I do it.

Comment: Spring already does all of this, and quite verbosely. It should already be in your logs.

Comment: Thanks for your reply skaffman. The problem is that I have several modules in my app, and would like to have a common place where I log whether each of these modules are loaded ok, so I can use that information for other purposes (GUI representation, etc). 

Is there something like a listener in Spring where I can "catch" those events?

Thanks
G.

Comment: Spring logs using Apache Commons Logging. Are you saying you want to programmatically catch these events?

Comment: I guess it should be programmatically as I need to log them in my own log file?

Answer (score 1):

Finally managed to do this. Added a logger in my log4j.properties for the ContextLoader class, with a level of ERROR. Then attached my new appender to that logger and this way I get all context loading errors in my new log file.

Thanks
G.